# Appwidget does not update correctly

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, android-loader, android-appwidget-list

I developed an appwidget, and it's a collection widget and use a Loader to retrieve the data from a database, and when a user clicks on the list item, that items details will be saved into a bundle in an intent, and the main activity will be launched with the bundled info displayed to the user.

My code works as intended; however, I am concerned with possible edge cases in how widgets actually work, initialize, and update that I have not thought of. I have discovered one edge case after thinking my code was working correctly for around 5 days now. Again, I am new to widget development, and the API for widgets took a lot for me to wrap my head around.

## Issue

Everything with my appwidget seems to work correctly on my phone, but on my Tablet it works correctly AFTER opening up the app and adding a new widget to the home screen. If I don't open the app first, then nothing is displayed in my widget.

Also, if my tablet is restarted or powered on-off, then my current widgets won't display anything. Even after opening up my app, I specifically have to add a new widget for my other widgets to get updated.

For my phone, I will rarely have issues with nothing being displayed on the widget unless I add another widget. At least I can't reproduce anything and guarantee that it will not work like on the tablet.

**So how can this work almost completely fine on my phone, but have issues all the time on my tablet? And is there a way to make sure my data is available whether I open on the app or not, and whether or not I restart my device?**

## Code

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/ciscorucinski/CapstoneProject/tree/master/app/src/hub). Links directly to my Hub Flavor that implements the appwidget (java and res folders, and manifest file)

### App Widget Provider

```
public class ResumeHubWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String LAUNCH_RESUME_ACTION = "io.github.ciscorucinski.personal.intro.hub.LAUNCH_RESUME_ACTION";

    private static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, ResumeHubWidgetProvider.class);
    }

    private static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                        int appWidgetId) {

        Intent serviceIntent = MyWidgetService.createIntent(context);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.resume_hub_list_widget);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list, serviceIntent);

        Intent widgetProviderIntent = ResumeHubWidgetProvider.createIntent(context);
        widgetProviderIntent.setAction(ResumeHubWidgetProvider.LAUNCH_RESUME_ACTION);
        widgetProviderIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, widgetProviderIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_list, pendingIntent);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // There may be multiple similar widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(LAUNCH_RESUME_ACTION)) {

            Timber.i("Intent Action is LAUNCH_RESUME_ACTION");

            // Open the Resume activity with the user selected resume info
            Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(CREATE_INTENT_BUNDLE);
            context.startActivity(ResumeActivity
                    .createIntentWithFlags(context, bundle,
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        }

        int appWidgetIds[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, ResumeHubWidgetProvider.class));
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widget_list);

        super.onReceive(context, intent);

    }
}
```

### Adapter

```
class HubWidgetAdapter implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory,
        Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener<List<Resume.People>> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Resume.People> data;
    private int appWidgetId;
    private PeopleLoader loader;

    HubWidgetAdapter(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        Resume.People person = data.get(position);

        view.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, person.seeking_position());
        view.setTextColor(android.R.id.text1, Color.BLACK);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putLong(ResumeActivity.ID, person._id());
        bundle.putString(ResumeActivity.NAME, person.name());
        bundle.putString(ResumeActivity.EMAIL, person.email());
        bundle.putString(ResumeActivity.PHONE, person.phone());
        bundle.putString(ResumeActivity.GITHUB, person.github());
        bundle.putString(ResumeActivity.LINKEDIN, person.linkedin());
        bundle.putString(ResumeActivity.SEEKING, person.seeking_position());

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(CREATE_INTENT_BUNDLE, bundle);

        Timber.i("Bundled Person%s", intent);
        view.setOnClickFillInIntent(android.R.id.text1, intent);

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(Loader<List<Resume.People>> loader, List<Resume.People> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if (loader != null) {

            loader.unregisterListener(this);
            loader.cancelLoad();
            loader.stopLoading();
            loader = null;

        }

        data = null;

    }

    @Override public void onDataSetChanged() {

        loader = new PeopleLoader(context);
        loader.registerListener(0, this);
        loader.startLoading();

    }

    @Override public int getCount() { return data.size(); }
    @Override public RemoteViews getLoadingView() { return null; }
    @Override public int getViewTypeCount() { return 1; }
    @Override public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
    @Override public boolean hasStableIds() { return true; }

}
```

### Service

```
public class MyWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

    static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, MyWidgetService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new HubWidgetAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }

}
```

### Manifest (Hub Flavor)

The Hub flavor is the only aspect of my code that has appwidgets, so I am only including the Hub Manifest file here that is merged into the main Manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="io.github.ciscorucinski.personal.intro.ui.ResumeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <receiver android:name="io.github.ciscorucinski.personal.intro.hub.ResumeHubWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/resume_hub_list_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="io.github.ciscorucinski.personal.intro.hub.MyWidgetService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```